# How do i replace a specific combination of integer and string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace a python list with a deck of cards with symbols.

I have tried using Pythons replace function, but i assume the best solution for this is probably based on regular expression replacement.

The desired result would be this:

```
"Ah" => "A♥"
"5h" => "5♥"
```

etc.

Currently the list features items like this:
[Player name], [Player wallet], [1st player card], [2nd player card]

This could be i.e.:

```
["Don Johnson", 100, "Ks", "5d"]
["Davey Jones", 100, "4c", "3h"]
```

Any help for this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

(Edited for clarification on request - Thanks for all the input so far!)

Comment: _I have tried using Pythons replace function_ Show us the actual code that you tried.  We can't fix it if we don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Provide more example cases of what you exactly want. From the two cases you have given, it seems that you just want to replace `h` with `♥`

Comment: No, regular expression is to complex for that kind of task. Just use `replace()`.

Comment: Just those 2 examples are not enough to draw a definitive conclusion as to what “combination of integer and string” you want to be replaced and what with/when

Answer (score 2):

Here, we can simply use four simple expressions and make that replacement that we wish:

```
([AKJQ0-9]{1,2})h
([AKJQ0-9]{1,2})d
```

and similarly the other two.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cyEqzb/1/)

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"([AKJQ0-9]{1,2})h"

test_str = ("Ah\n"
    "10h")

subst = "\\1♥"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you had just a list of cards then it would probably look something like this:

```
cards = ['2h', '2s', '2c', '2d', '3h', '3s', '3c', '3d', '4h', '4s', '4c', '4d', '5h', '5s', '5c', '5d', '6h', '6s', '6c', '6d', '7h', '7s', '7c', '7d', '8h', '8s', '8c', '8d', '9h', '9s', '9c', '9d', '10h', '10s', '10c', '10d', 'Ah', 'As', 'Ac', 'Ad', 'Kh', 'Ks', 'Kc', 'Kd', 'Jh', 'Js', 'Jc', 'Jd', 'Qh', 'Qs', 'Qc', 'Qd']
```

If so then just use a dict and a comprehension:

```
suits = {'h': '♥', 's': '♠', 'c': '♣', 'd': '♦'}
new_cards = [''.join(rank)+suits[suit] for *rank, suit in cards]
```

Output for this is:

```
['2♥', '2♠', '2♣', '2♦', '3♥', '3♠', '3♣', '3♦', '4♥', '4♠', '4♣', '4♦', '5♥', '5♠', '5♣', '5♦', '6♥', '6♠', '6♣', '6♦', '7♥', '7♠', '7♣', '7♦', '8♥', '8♠', '8♣', '8♦', '9♥', '9♠', '9♣', '9♦', '10♥', '10♠', '10♣', '10♦', 'A♥', 'A♠', 'A♣', 'A♦', 'K♥', 'K♠', 'K♣', 'K♦', 'J♥', 'J♠', 'J♣', 'J♦', 'Q♥', 'Q♠', 'Q♣', 'Q♦']
```

For your solution you could define a function that corrects the card:

```
def fix_card(card):
    suits = {'h': '♥', 's': '♠', 'c': '♣', 'd': '♦'}
    *rank, suit = card
    return ''.join(rank)+suits[suit]
```

Then just use it like this:

```
player = ["Don Johnson", 100, "Ks", "5d"]
player[2] = fix_card(player[2])
player[3] = fix_card(player[3])
print(player)
#["Don Johnson", 100, "K♣", "5♦"]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, regex is not needed for a simple replacement like this. Just use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
>>> cards = ['Ah', '5h']
>>> [s.replace('h', '♥') for s in cards]
['A♥', '5♥']
```